# List<Integer>, удалить элемент по значению

Tags: java, коллекции

Например, в функции remove(obj). Проблема в том, что число в скобках считывается как индекс. В данном случае идет выполнение remove(index).

Как это можно изменить?

Пример:

```
    public class L16_Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedList<Integer> arr = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                arr.add(i+5);
            out.println(arr);
            // output: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
            arr.remove(5);
            out.println(arr);
            // output: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У `LinkedList` есть два метода:

1. `remove(Object o)` - удаляет первый найденный элемент по значению.
2. `remove(int index)` - удаляет элемент на позиции index.

Вы используете второй вариант, чтобы воспользоваться первым нужно преобразовать int к Integer:

```
public class L16_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> arr = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            arr.add(i+5);
        out.println(arr);

        arr.remove((Integer)5); // удаляет по значению

        out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: @СветланаПопова, если данный ответ решил Вашу проблему, пожалуйста, отметьте его как правильный (галочка слева от ответа).